# Rails 4 ActionMailer - How to capture connection and SMTP errors when using deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am using ActionMailer deliver_later  w ActiveJobs /  Sidekiq using :

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

as I am testing in dev mode w MailCatcher, the only error I can catch is Errno::ECONNREFUSED, setting port 1026 instead of 1025

When I test deliver_now, I get the Errno::ECONNREFUSED error raised, which is fine

```
begin
   MessageMailer.contact_me_email(@message).deliver_now
   rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Net::SMTPAuthenticationError, Net::SMTPServerBusy, Net::SMTPSyntaxError, Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPUnknownError => e
     flash[:error] = "Problems sending mail. Please try again later"
     # delete message or resend it ?
     byebug
     @message.destroy
     format.html { render :new }
   end
```

However, when I request a deliver_later, then the request is sore in the sidekiq mailers queue, and the error is not captured...

```
       begin
   MessageMailer.contact_me_email(@message).deliver_later(wait: 1.minute ) # in mailers queue
   rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Net::SMTPAuthenticationError, Net::SMTPServerBusy, Net::SMTPSyntaxError, Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPUnknownError => e
     flash[:error] = "Problems sending mail. Please try again later"
     # delete message or resend it ?
     byebug
     @message.destroy
     format.html { render :new }
   end
```

How can I capture and rescue from SMTP errors in this case ? I guess it's a Sidekiq responsibility to handle it ... any hint   welcome..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ActiveJobs allows you to rescue errors that occur when the job is performed using the `rescue_from` method.  See [the api](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions).  You will need to implement this method in your ActiveJob subclasses.

Since ActionMailer uses DeliveryJobs to deliver the messages as jobs you will need to add a rescue_from method to this class to handle the exception.

For example, you could place in `config/initializers/action_mailer.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::DeliveryJob.rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
    Rails.logger.error "Original record not found: #{@serialized_arguments.join(', ')}"
end
```

This will cleanly rescue any StandardErrors, and simply log them instead of raising an exception.   I implemented this myself to quiet Rollbar.

Since it's a corner case, it's a good idea to test it as well:

`spec/initializers/action_mailer_spec.rb`:

```
RSpec.describe 'ActionMailer::DeliveryJob error recovery' do

   it 'should log the deserialization errors' do
     @user = create(:user)
     MyCustomMailer.send_something(@user).deliver_later
     @user.destroy

     expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).at_least(:once)
     Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
   end

end
```

Comment: Is @serialized_arguments something known to DeliveryJob? I am trying to send an email to each of a number of email addresses newly written to a DB table, and I would like to somehow mark the email address as invalid if sending fails. For this, I would have to access the DB record. Is this possible?